# How to set/get full value hidden field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting value 'abc\ra12345' to a hidden field. When I try to retrieve the value, am getting 'abca12345'. Please suggest how to set/get full value? Thanks.

```
$("#hiduserid").val('abc\ra12345');

alert($("#hiduserid").val());
```

Here is fiddler link: https://jsfiddle.net/qgq3q40u/3/

Comment: Are you trying to explicitly add a special character? (\r = carriage return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double \ as it's is considered as an escape char

```js
$("#hiduserid").val('abc\\ra12345');

alert($("#hiduserid").val());
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize about the \r - carriage return.

Comment: You are welcome ^_^ please accept my answer as the right one ^_-